# Missing Reference name heading, or wrong appears two references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, elsarticle

I am using elsarticle template to add my reference. However, I met two issues

1. The number before a book/paper name is disappeared
2. First, the reference heading did not include in my paper. After add \def\bibsection{\section*{References}}, my papers has two Reference name. How to correct them?

Thank you so much

In tex file

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}
...
Random citation \cite{DUMMY:1} embeddeed in text.
\newpage

\bibliography{elsarticle-template-harv}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
```

In bib file:

```
@BOOK{DUMMY:1,
AUTHOR="John Doe",
TITLE="The Book without Title",
PUBLISHER="Dummy Publisher",
YEAR="2100",
}
```

The wrong output is
[image]

Comment: I have re-tagged your question since it is not about `biblatex`. The style `elsarticle-harv` is a "Harvard style" bibliography style and will give "Author Year" references, so there is no number. Use `el­sar­ti­cle-num` or `el­sar­ti­cle-num-names` instead.

Comment: Is there any news here?